# getting typeerror: failed to execute 'createobjecturl' on 'url' error while trying to save the file in local

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to save the file in local. When user clicks on attachment I am trying to save the file into local. I am getting typeerror: failed to execute 'createobjecturl' on 'url' error while doing this. Can someone point me where I am doing wrong. below is my code

```
function openFile() {
    var fileName = $(this).closest(".file-box").find(".file-name").text();
    var encodedFileName = encodeURIComponent(fileName);
    $(document.body).showLoaderWithText("Downloading File");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Procurement/Open",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ savInitId: mv.options.savInitId, fileName: encodedFileName }),
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: "blob"
        },
        global: false,
        success: function (blob) {
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
            } else {
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                $(document.body).resetLoader();

            }
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
            if (/^not found$/ig.test(thrownError)) {
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            $(document.body).resetLoader();
        }
    });
}
```

in controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage Open(int savInitId, string fileName)
    {
        var fullPath = CommonService.ServerSharedDrivePath + savInitId.ToString();
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
        FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(fileName);

        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var fileStream = files[0].Open(FileMode.Open);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = fileName };
            return response;
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
```

Comment: May I know what kind of project you are working on? What browser did you used? You have successfully hit the endpoint right? And then getting the error here in this line `window.URL.createObjectUR` have you checked the console?

Comment: I am working mvc project. I successfully hit the end point and  I am getting error at window.URL.createObjectUR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am getting typeerror: failed to execute 'createobjecturl' on 'url'
> error while doing this. Can someone point me where I am doing wrong.

Actually, there's no wrong or incorrect snippet within your shared code. Dpending on browser and its version, if the createObjectURL method doesn't exist wihtin the browser, the variable will be undefined, and trying to invoke it will throw an error which you are getting now.

I am not sure, if you are getting the same error in all browser. Instead of using only `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` you can also try `window.webkit.createObjectURL(blob)` or even you can set if conditionals, because you never know which brower wouldn't support, so you can do as following:

```
       if (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL) {
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                $(document.body).resetLoader();
        }
        else if (window.webkitURL && window.webkitURL.createObjectURL) {
           
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                var url = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                $(document.body).resetLoader();
        }
```

Apart from above way, you also can create new blob object and assign your blob which you are getting from server  Make sure, you have checked the blob whether its null before assigning. Like below:

```
var newblob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(blob, null, 2)], { type: "image/png" });
var newblobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

**Note:** First check if youb are getting undefined here in `window.URL.createObjectURL` that's means your browser doesn't support `window.URL.` so that you can try alternative. Its obvious that issue belongs to `window.URL` here. In additiona to this, also check for null of your `blob` object which also cause the error. [Please refer to the official document here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#creating_a_blob)

Comment: Glad to assist you.

Comment: I had a kinda similar problem when receiving my video blob from another browser thru a p2p connection.

This line: ```var newblob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(blob)], { type: "video/webm" });
``` , recreating the blob using the one received, solved my problem

Comment: It would be great if you could  post your real scenario and description along with the reproducible code snippet in new question it would be easier to assist you.